# DVD Investigation class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dvd

Does anyone know of a class/component FreeWare/ShareWare/BuyWare that can investigate a DVD structure (and - if possible - a BluRay structure) and return information about what is on the DVD with regards to number of titles, and title information for each title?

It must return the following information for each title:
Video Encoding (MPEG-1/MPEG-2), Video Resolution (352x240, 352x288, 480x480, 480x576, 544x480, 544x576, 704x480, 704x576, 720x480, 720x576), Anamorphic?, Duration in Seconds/milliseconds, FrameRate (23.976, 24.000, 25.000, 29.997, 30.000), Subtitle Tracks and Audio Tracks.

For each Audio Track in each individual title, the following information is needed:
Audio Format (DTS, Dolby Digital, LPCM, MPEG), Channel Count (Main Channels + Subwoofer, must be able to handle f.ex. Dolby Digital 3.1 or 4.0), Language

For each subtitle track in each individual title, the Language of the track is needed.

All this information can be obtained from the VIDEO_TS/VTS_xx_y IFO files, but I haven't been able to figure out the exact code needed that can handle all my DVDs.

I have a skeleton class located at http://www.heartware.dk/DVD.PAS that would satisfy me needs.

Comment: Are you tried reading the specification of the IFO format http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/ifo.html ?

Comment: Yes, and I got a long way using that, but on some DVDs my code crashes, and I haven't been able to figure out the correct code that would allow me to read the information from all my DVDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Torry.net? http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=168

Seems "VisioForge Video Info" can do what you want, but it's commercial (it's cheap anyway) so ask it's author first.

May be other options at that directory can do what you need too.

Comment: Thanks - it seems like that library can do nicely (only thing I couldn't see it returns is the region codes, but since I bought it with source included, I can update it myself to return that as well). I have updated my skeleton class to return the information using this library - it can be downloaded from http://www.heartware.dk/DVD.zip